# How to replace a string in a column with REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table which references mobile numbers, but they are not all in international format. In the `mobile` column, I have many records and I need to change just all records with a `1` as first char to `491` and leave the rest unchanged. I tried this:

```
UPDATE test
SET mobile=(REPLACE (mobile,'1','491'));
```

But it turns a number like `1512231178` to `4915122349149178`. It should be `491512231178`. I think I need something like `REGEXP '^1'` in the `REPLACE`.

How can I do this with a simple update?

Comment: MariaDB's `REGEXP_REPLACE()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Giorgi Nakeuri's clever problem substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31055566/297408) (prefixing for replacement) will work for your particular example. In other cases, where it is impossible to simplify the problem in such a way, you could use the [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) string function, which does almost exactly what you want: replaces a substring of a specific length at a specific position with another substring. It does not allow you to also specify that the old substring match a specific value but you could use a WHERE clause for that, as Giorgi did:

```
UPDATE
  test
SET
  mobile = INSERT(mobile, 1, 1, '491')
WHERE
  mobile LIKE '1%'
;
```

If you needed to parametrise both the old and the new substring, this is how you could go about it:

```
UPDATE
  test
SET
  mobile = INSERT(mobile, 1, LENGTH(@OldValue), @NewValue)
WHERE
  mobile LIKE CONCAT(@OldValue, '%')
;
```

Comment: mysql> SET mobile = CONCAT('49', mobile)
    -> where mobile like '1%';
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'mobile'

Comment: `SET mobile...` isn't supposed to be a separate statement, it's part of the UPDATE actually.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do like this:

```
UPDATE test SET mobile = '49' + mobile
where mobile like '1%'
```

Comment: nice solution - it runs with no error, but 1512231178 becomes 1512231227 it adds 49. mobile is varchar(30) NOT NULL

Comment: @Mucki, hmm, it is very strange, are you sure mobile us varchar? try `SET mobile = '49' + cast(mobile as varchar(30))`